# SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined in python flask

Tags: python, linux, flask, annotations, virtualenv

i'm getting this error and i'm using flask 2.2.2 with python3.10 in a virtualevn on a centOS7 server. I have check online but all pointing to upgrade python to 3.7 and above which obviously i'm using 3.10 and annotation is meant to work with the version

```
File ".../venv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from . import json as json
mod_wsgi (pid=11889): Failed to exec Python script file '.../wsgi.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=11889): Exception occurred processing WSGI script

File ".../venv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 1

SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Virtual environment was created using

```
python3 -m venv venv2
```

This is being used in a wsgi.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import sys 
import site 

site.addsitedir('.../venv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/...') 

from app import app as application
```

It is called by httpd with WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIScriptAlias added inside virtualHost like this

```
WSGIDaemonProcess appname python-path=/../site.com:/.../venv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / .../wsgi.py
```

Reinstalled flask and upgrade all packages

Comment: That error should only be possible if a pre-3.7.0b1 interpreter is being used. Could you comment on how that virtual environment was created and how it's being used?

Comment: Please add that information to your question with an [edit]. The issue here is that you're trying to add the site-packages directory of one interpreter to a _different interpreter's_ search path. That's not the same as actually using your virtual environment's interpreter. `wsgi.py` is being run with whatever `python` is (presumably the system Python 2 interpreter). You probably want to run `wsgi.py` with the interpreter from your virtual environment. Depending on how `wsgi.py` is being invoked, that might be as simple as fixing the shebang to use the venv2 interpreter.

Comment: Please how do i achive that, running wsgi.py from my virtual environment. the current wsgi.py file is currently on the app base path